# Waking up LPC1768 with Magic Packet

Tags: c++, mbed

I'm trying to wakeup a LPC1768 from sleep-mode with a magic packet. But somehow the device is not waking up.

FYI: the device wakes up when I enable the "Wakeup at any packet"-option.

Where is my error here?

```
//Interrupt Enable Register
int *IntEnable = (int*) 0x50000FE4;
#define WakeupIntEn 13  

//Receive Filter Control Register
int *RxFilterCtrl = (int*) 0x50000200;
#define RxFilterEnWoL       13      
#define MagicPacketEnWoL    12

int main() {

NVIC_EnableIRQ(ENET_IRQn);
NVIC_SetVector(ENET_IRQn, (uint32_t) MyEthernetHandler);

*IntEnable |= (1 << WakeupIntEn);
*RxFilterCtrl = (1 << MagicPacketEnWoL);

__WFI();

...
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the magic packet is valid ? How do you generate it ?

Comment: I use another LPC1768. The packet I send looks like
FF FF FF FF FF FF + 16 times the MAC address of the sleeping device

Comment: But did you check that the packet actually transmitted is correct ? My point is that it is much more likely that the bug is in the sending MCU than in the one-line configuration (since you said it worked with generic wol).

Comment: Yes I did. I printed the received frame into a terminal tool before I sent the device to sleep.

Furthermore, I tried sending a Magic Packet with different "Magic Packet Sender"-tools and checked the outgoing packets via Wireshark.

Comment: If you are sure that the packet is valid, and all you did is replace `RxFilterEnWoL` by `MagicPacketEnWoL`, then I don't see anything wrong. Maybe it's actually working but you don't see it because of something else ? How do you check that the MCU woke up ? What is in `MyEthernetHandler` ?

Comment: `MyEthernetHandler` does nothing but print something in the terminal that I know it got called. Like mentioned before it works when I enable the wakeup for any packet

Comment: Does it change anything if you enable perfect address filter ? The `AcceptPerfectEn` bit in `RxFilterCtrl`.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. I also tried enabling different bits (`AcceptBroadcastEn`, `AcceptUnicastEn`, ...) in the `RxFilterCtrl` register, but still the same behaviour...